# Scanner Canon Pixma G2000 not detected on scangearmp

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing, scanner, canon

I installed lubuntu 18.04. I search on google, "How to install scanner driver canon g2000 ubuntu 18.04". I was founded [this](https://blog.droidzone.in/2017/09/07/getting-canon-pixma-g2000-driver-working-on-ubuntu-xenial/)

I was did this :

```
sudo apt install libsane-dev libtool-bin libusb-dev sane-utils libsane-extras xsane
```

And the output was :

```
[sudo] password for arlank: 
Sedang membaca daftar paket... Selesai
Membangun pohon ketergantungan        
Membaca informasi yang tersedia... Selesai
libsane-dev sudah versi terbaru (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2).
libtool-bin sudah versi terbaru (2.4.6-2).
libusb-dev sudah versi terbaru (2:0.1.12-31).
sane-utils sudah versi terbaru (1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2).
libsane-extras sudah versi terbaru (1.0.22.5).
xsane sudah versi terbaru (0.999-5ubuntu2).
0 dimutakhirkan, 0 baru terinstal, 0 akan dihapus dan 15 tidak akan dimutakhirkan.
```

I was type :

```
debuild -tc
```

And the output was :

```
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of scangearmp-common_2.30.orig.tar.gz, scangearmp-common_2.30.orig.tar.bz2,
scangearmp-common_2.30.orig.tar.lzma,  scangearmp-common_2.30.orig.tar.xz or scangearmp.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n) y
```

Continued :

```
gpg: skipped "Canon Inc. <sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp>": No secret key
gpg: /tmp/debsign.anT3qloY/scangearmp-common_2.30-1.dsc: clear-sign failed: No secret key
debsign: gpg error occurred!  Aborting....
debuild: fatal error at line 1081:
running debsign failed
```

Then, I install scangearmp :

```
sudo dpkg -i ../scangearmp-common_2.30-1_amd64.deb
```

I test with :

```
scanimage -L
```

The output was :

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

I test again with :

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1795 [G2000 series]) at libusb:002:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

The printer detected on usb. But not detected on scangearmp :
[look this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuqjH.png)

Can anyone help me ?? I was newbie (':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I am going to start to answer you; there are 3 folders in scangearmp2_3.30-1_amd64.deb; ideally you would alter **80-canon_mfp2.rules**

I enclose a snapshot of the relevant lines for the G3000 in it[image]

Ideally I think you would edit that file inside the scangear package; that is what the link you gave was trying to do; I don't think they told you all the steps;.. so ..

maybe more simply, what about you create a udev rule using gedit so open a terminal and install gedit with `sudo apt install gedit` and then paste this into the terminal

`gksudo gedit /etc/sane.d/G2000.conf`

that should be a blank file that appears so enter

```
#G2000
```

ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1795", MODE="666"

where the #G2000 is on one line and the ATTR starts the next line below; sorry, the editing in the dialogue makes it look strange ..

paste the above into the file; SAVE; close

go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100713401.html and click to download and save what will be scangearmp2-3.30-1-deb.tar.gz so paste into the terminal;

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf scangearmp2-3.30-1-deb.tar.gz

cd scangearmp2-3.30-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

and watch as the install script runs as it will ask you questions;

then type or paste into the terminal

```
scangearmp
```

and I wonder if it then opens for you?

Comment: Thanks, this is work. But, i must install sane-backends, scangearmp, scangearmp2 too. Thank you so much.