# Cannot persuade ubuntu 18.04 to detect and run Canon G2000 series scanner

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, canon, simplescan

I have a Canon Pixma G2100 multifunctional that prints very well but I cannot use the scanner.
My Linux is a Xubuntu 18.04 updated.

I followed this link to install the scanner (option B - from source):
https://blog.droidzone.in/tag/sane/

Both commands `autoreconf` and `debuild` show many warnings and some errors but the `scangearmp-common_2.30-1_amd64.deb`is generated and can be installed without error messages.

I add the definition in the 2 lines below to `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp.rules` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-canon_mfp2.rules`

```
#G2000 series
ATTR{idVendor}==”04a9″, ATTR{idProduct}==”1795″, MODE=”666″
```

At this point, lsusb and sane-find-scanner detect my usb scanner but scanimage, simple scan and xsane don't.

Another try, using the procedure of the link below give the same result:
[Scanner Canon Pixma G2000 not detected on scangearmp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052058/scanner-canon-pixma-g2000-not-detected-on-scangearmp)

I find that this multifunctional is old in the US and Europe and never had an original Canon linux driver. It was sold as a novelty in Brazil last year and I bought it thinking I could find a sane driver.

Does anyone has a solution for this problematic scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Since your device listed as supported [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON), it should work. Based on your description, I assume, that the installed sane version is not up-to-date. I had the same problem, that `lsusb` and `sane-find-scanner` detected my scanner, but `scanimage -L` failed. You can check your sane backend version by running:

> `scanimage -V`

You have two ways to update your sane package. Choose one of them, not both.

**OPTION 1**

The suggestion from markling to use the repository([Install Canon LiDE 300 / 400 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107632/install-canon-lide-300-400-on-ubuntu-18-04)) worked for me.

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`

After the installation, you should be able to identify your scanner by executing `scanimage -L`.

**OPTION 2**

The compilation and installation of the latest sane is in my opinion the cleaner solution. However, you have to do more and be patient.

As preparation, you have to install the prerequisites:

> `sudo apt install build-essential libieee1284-3 gphoto2 autoconf automake libtool gettext git autopoint autoconf-archive pkg-config libjpeg-dev`

Now, you can enter the folder of your choice and run:

> `git clone https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends.git`
>
> `cd backends`
>
> `./autogen.sh`
>
> `BACKENDS="canon pixma" ./configure`
>
> `make`
>
> `make install`

After the installation, you should be able to identify your scanner by executing `scanimage -L`.

By compiling the newest version, the backend status in my system changed from *1.0.27* to *1.0.29*.

Answer (score 0):

@rgagit,

@thierryhucahrd had noted that the scanimage and sane versions were out of date and informed me that the latest version already recognized scanners in the Canon G2000 family.
But scanimage insisted on maintaining version 1.0.27

sudo apt install sane-utils libsane libsane-common
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
libsane is already the newest version (1.0.29 + git20200320-bionic0).
libsane-common is already the newest version (1.0.29 + git20200320-bionic0).
sane-utils is already the newest version (1.0.29 + git20200320-bionic0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.27; backend version 1.0.27

The scanimage and backend version was always indicated as 1.0.27

I located scanimage using:

sudo find /usr -name scanimage
/usr/local/bin/scanimage
/usr/bin/scanimage

I deleted the two occurrences of scanimage.

I removed the sane with:

sudo apt remove sane

i downloaded sane-backends-1.0.29.tar.gz from:
https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/releases

unzipped and compiled with:
./configure
make
sudo make install

scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.29; backend version 1.0.29

The scanner is now recognized by scanimage, simple scan and xsane

Your second solution is similar to this one, but it is cleaner than mine.
Thank you very much for your help and for Thierry's too.