# 18.04: Can't scan from Canon G2110 multi-function printer with xsane & simple scan

Tags: scanner, canon, xsane, simplescan

I use my Canon multifunction printer PIXMA G2110  with my laptop and doesn't make troubles, but when I try to use it as a scanner w/ xsane or simple scan, it is not recognized.

I don't know if there's another app to use, or maybe drivers don't exist to use it as a scanner w/ Ubuntu 18.04?

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: There are two different Canon G2110 multifunction printers with scanning. Do you have the Pixma G2110 https://www.cla.canon.com/cla/en/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/g_series_inkjet_printers/pixma_g2110 or the DR-G2110 https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/scanners/document-scanner/imageformula-dr-g2110-production-scanner ? Please click [edit] and add to the question which you have.

Comment: See related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216382/cannot-persuade-ubuntu-18-04-to-detect-and-run-canon-g2000-series-scanner?rq=1